# Remembering password when logging into SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, password

We are using SharePoint 2019 on-premise in a test system.

Testing users would like to remember their user name and password when logging-in (there is no option in prompt box to remember). I searched around but found no solution.

Is there anyone know how to do that or any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to save the password in browser?
If so, you could refer to:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/remember-passwords-and-fill-out-web-forms-for-internet-explorer-11-6883f6ce-0d1c-c2b9-e21e-705976d1c886

Since you are using Microsoft Edge, have you tried Settings > Profiles > Passwords > Turn on Offer to save passwords?

Or you want to save the password in Virtual Machine？
You could right click the server, select property and set it here:

[image]

Comment: Dear Yi Lu. What I mentioned is when user logging in to Sharepoint web page using MS Edge browser.

Comment: Hi @mountaineer07, I have updated the answer.